# Проблема с таймером. Проскакивают секунды

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Имеется таймер с привязкой к текущему времени. Но в некоторых браузерах(как пример ФФ в виндовс 10) просчитывает секунды по 2, либо просто быстро пролетают секунды и потом уходит в минус

```
$scope.time = {};
$scope.time.s = "00";
$scope.time.m = "2";

$scope.oldTime = new Date().getTime();
$scope.endTime = Math.floor(($scope.oldTime + 120000) /1000);
$scope.twoMin = Math.ceil(Math.abs(($scope.endTime - ($scope.oldTime/1000))));

var value = form.phone.substr(0, 2);
var config = configs.mobile_codes;

$scope.tick = function () {

    $scope.timeNow = new Date().getTime();
    $scope.timeNow = Math.floor($scope.timeNow/1000);
    $scope.buttonActive = false;


    if ($scope.timeNow >= $scope.endTime) {
        $interval.cancel($scope.timer);
        $scope.avail = true;
        $scope.time.s = '00';
        $scope.time.m = '0';
        $scope.buttonActive = true;
    } else {
        $scope.twoMin--;
        $scope.time.s = ($scope.twoMin % 60) < 10 ? "0" + $scope.twoMin % 60 : $scope.twoMin % 60;
        $scope.time.m = Math.floor($scope.twoMin / 60);
    }
};

$scope.timer = $interval($scope.tick, 1000);
```

Html

```
<span class="help-block">{{ 'AUTH.CODE-RE' | translate }}: {{time.m}}:{{time.s}}</span>
```

Попробовал еще так и тоже прощелкивает. То задерживается то прощелкивает на 2 секунды. в итоге то суммарно выдерживает то время что нужно. Но скачет туда сюда.

```
 // Set the date we're counting down to
        var countDownDate = new Date().getTime() + 120000;

// Update the count down every 1 second
        var x = setInterval(function() {

            // Get todays date and time
            var now = new Date().getTime();

            // Find the distance between now an the count down date
            var distance = countDownDate - now;

            // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

            // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

            // If the count down is finished, write some text
            if (distance < 0) {
                clearInterval(x);
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
            }
        }, 1000);
```

Comment: Метод setInterval насколько я помню срабатывает не сразу, а когда у браузера есть ресурсы на выполнение этой функции, и поэтому получается разброс по времени (попробуйте вывести distance в консоль). В Вашем случае я бы использовал счетчик и уменьшал его в этой функции, или задал время 125000, чтоб разброс приходился не на границы секунды.

Comment: Неправильно указал разницу времени, надо `new Date().getTime() + 120500;`

Comment: спасибо. помогло